problems to archive build version in xCode using flutter
im trying to archive a bundle apk and send to my test flight. Build is Success and im not undestanding why is no working as before updating flutter.

here is the message that shows up.
enter image description here


what should i do for sent it to test flight ?

have you already run "flutter build ios"?

yes, it doesnt work

if you have not run your application on read device yet, you should try to do it. a week ago I had issue when I could not upload my app to app store because I have not launched app on real devices

Change your run destination, from iPhone 15 Pro to Any iOS device (arm64)

From TN3109: Resolving common archiving issues:

The Archive command in the Product menu is disabled
You can choose Product > Archive in Xcode after meeting these requirements:

You’ve selected a real device or build-only device as the run destination in the scheme building your app. Apps built with simulator
SDKs can’t be archived nor submitted to the App Store;
see Running Your App in the Simulator or on a Device.
You’ve enabled the archive action for the scheme building your app.


Similar question:

Having trouble archiving my Xcode project because of an "Invalid Run Destination"

